# How would you tidy up this Mysql logic

Tags: mysql

I'm using [morris chart](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/) to show daily basis data. 
Say One Human(manID) daily eat 3 times morning , noon, after_noon. So i input data like this

```
Table: table
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| manId(AI)(PK) |  date | schedules | amount | blah | [....]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When i query to display morris chart data then it will come up with each data like this

```
 102 - 01/01/2016 - 0.5 KG (morning time data)
 102 - 01/01/2016 - 0.5 KG (noon time data)
 102 - 01/01/2016 - 0.5 KG (after_noon time data)
 103 - 01/01/2016 - 0.5 KG (morning time data)
```

What i want to do that it will be show daily wise like this

```
102 - 01/01/2016 - 1.5 KG (Sum all schedules)
103 - 02/01/2016 - 1.5 KG (Sum all schedules)
104 - 03/01/2016 - 1.5 KG (Sum all schedules)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` on `date` column and `sum` all the values.

```
SELECT id,date,SUM(amount)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY date;
```